# Escape HTML on import

Tags: python, html, flask, escaping, jinja2

I'm using Flask with Jinja2 templates to create custom forms. In these forms, I need part of the form to change when a field's value changes.

Basically, my form has a `select#content-type` where I can chose a content type and then a `fieldset#content` whose HTML should vary when the value of the `select` changes. I have several HTML templates depending on the value of the `select`.

My JS looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("select#content-type").change(function () {
            switch ($(this).val()) {
                case "type1":
                    var html = "{% include "type1.html" | escape %}";
                    $("fieldset#content").html(html);
                    break;
                // ...
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The thing is, the `escape` filter doesn't work in an `include` statement, nor does `safe`. How can I achieve this, or is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few solutions for this.

An easy way to achieve this is just hide all the content type dependent part of the form using a helper CSS class, e.g. `.hide {display: none;}`, and when the client selects something just remove this class: `$("div#type1").removeClass("hide");` from the appropriate div.

Another way is loading the content type dependent part of the form using Ajax request. You can define a route like `/loadform` where the server reads the appropriate template file and prints it. Then you can inject the response HTML into the original form.

A third way is to submit the partially filled form using javascript when the client selects a content type, then render the complete form.